# Reduce header height after scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on webpage with quite a large header, about 180px. For a better user experience I want to reduce the size of header to about 100px once the user has started scrolling, everything is going smooth so far, however, I can't seem to get the logo to reduce the size of the logo in the header to well, or at least it's background size, any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/KQGyu/4/

code as follows -

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#header').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#header').data('size','small');
        $('#header').stop().animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
{
    if($('#header').data('size') == 'small')
    {
        $('#header').data('size','big');
        $('#header').stop().animate({
            height:'180px'
        },600);
    }  
}
});$(function(){
$('#header').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#header').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#header').data('size','small');
        $('#header').stop().animate({
            height:'100px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
{
    if($('#header').data('size') == 'small')
    {
        $('#header').data('size','big');
        $('#header').stop().animate({
            height:'180px'
        },600);
    }  
}
});
</script>










<script>
$(function(){
$('#logo').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#logo').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#logo').data('size','small');
        $('#logo').stop().animate({
            width:'59px',height:'63px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
{
    if($('#logo').data('size') == 'small')
    {
        $('#logo').data('size','big');
        $('#logo').stop().animate({
            width:'128px',height:'120px'
        },600);
    }  
}
});$(function(){
$('#logo').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 0)
{
    if($('#logo').data('size') == 'big')
    {
        $('#logo').data('size','small');
        $('#logo').stop().animate({
            width:'59px',height:'63px'
        },600);
    }
}
else
{
    if($('#logo').data('size') == 'small')
    {
        $('#logo').data('size','big');
        $('#logo').stop().animate({
            width:'128px',height:'120px'
        },600);
    }  
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't seem to get the logo to reduce the size"? What happens, do the header reduces? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: PLease provide a fiddle and paste your HTML code.

Comment: My header reduces in size, though for some reason it doesn't work on my jsfiddle, but the problem is my logo which reduces in size, however the background size doesn't seem to change leaving me with a cropped logo. I will add a fiddle to my original question. @LcSalazar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let the CSS do all the work. Encoding animation like this in javascript will lead a variety of kinds of pain.

Your JS should be as simple as this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        $('#header').addClass('small');
    } else {
        $('#header').removeClass('small');
    }
});
```

And your CSS sets up the two states, and how it transitions between them:

```
#header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #888;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;

    transition: font-size 0.5s, height 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: font-size 0.5s, height 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: font-size 0.5s, height 0.5s;

}

#header.small {
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

See it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/VLD8G/

Now you can scope anything you want different by the `#header.small` rule. For example:

```
#header .logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#header.small logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Or anything else you want to change. And the beauty is that your JS doesn't have to change at all.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Wayne seem to make sense. I will let you know how I get on! Really appreciate the help.

Comment: BINGO! Works like a charm @Alex Wayne Thanks a lot, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

here is vanilla js solution:

1. Add id="header" to header tag
2. Add css

```
#header {
  height: 100px;
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out
}
.header_small {
  height: 50px;
}
```

3. Add js

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    const $header = document.getElementById('header');
    if (!$header) {
        return;
    }
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 0 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0) {
        $header.classList.add('header_small');
    } else {
        $header.classList.remove('header_small');
    }
}
```